# PgAdmin Server Status Blank

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

good afternoon

I am facing a problem with pgAdmin - version 1.22.2 (Feb 11 2018, rev: REL-1_22_1)

In the tools -> server status

They are not listing the connections and processes, everything goes blank. Does anyone know how to fix it?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I see the same problem, same ubuntu and pgAdmin version. I noticed that it does show scrollbars for some of the views on one of my big servers so it has content for the views but it is not visible. Maybe building pgAdmin from source will solve the issue.

Comment: humm...more ideas?